# Populating coredata many-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Worker and Event Entity. I'm having trouble when creating a new worker for a Event the worker entity has a corresponding event but the event entity is not saving the workers.(shouldn't this be happening automatically when setting the inverse option)

```
   class Event: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var startTime: String
    @NSManaged var endTime: String
    @NSManaged var workers: NSMutableSet

    func addWorker(name: String, startTime: String, endTime: String) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        var worker: Worker = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Worker", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Worker

        worker.name = name
        worker.startTime = startTime
        worker.endTime = endTime
        worker.id = Worker.getNewWorkerId()
        worker.events.addObject(self)

        var error: NSError?

        if !managedContext.save(&error) {
            println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: everything is working now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also define the relationship to be "To Many" on both ends of the relation. To define the relationships as such, select the relationship in question and on the right-pane set 'Type' to 'To Many'.

Additionally, your many to many attributes in your subclasses of NSManagedObject should be of type NSSet and NSOrderedSet, not NSMutableSet. See the documentation here: [Managed Object Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1).

[image]

If you want to add any additional information about the relationship an 'associative' or 'join' entity will be required.
([CoreData Many-To-Many Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10))

Comment: Already defined the relationship to be "To Many" on both ends of the relation (working many-to-many example would be helpful)

Comment: Can I look at your project? Perhaps on bitbucket.

Comment: I will try to upload a modified version of your project later. When I had the built-in tool generate Managed Objects for your Worker and Event entities, it added the relationships as NSSet and NSOrderedSet (I assume you specified that one end of the relationship be ordered).

Comment: yes, i added it as ordered. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: You also want to change the NSMutableSet to NSSet. (You're welcome!) Also, for that change you will have to modify the way you are adding objects. I use the NSSet method, setByAddingObject (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/setByAddingObject:)

Comment: Sure. I have been quite busy lately, I will do it tonight.

Comment: You can tell that the event has saved the workers by looking at the number of workers in your OverviewViewController.